# Monitor Mac OS X HDD access

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, software-rec

I got an iMac 27" with a dying hard drive. 
Sometimes I got hight read/write access to the hard drive and I don't why.

Is there an program to monitor the access program specific? I want to know which program causes the high activities.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the command-line application `fs_usage` to monitor disk use live. It requires elevated privileges.

Enter in Terminal:

```
sudo fs_usage
```

The only problem is, without filtering for applications, you probably won't be able to read the output fast enough. To filter for specific applications:

```
sudo fs_usage Finder
```

It wants the internal application name that is also used e.g. in `ps`, not the name of the application bundle.

---

Another option is `opensnoop`: It only monitors file open activity and contains less noise than `fs_usage` but you need e.g. `grep` to filter the output.

It contains the numeric file descriptor returned from the file open call or `-1` if it failed. This doesn't have to indicate a real problem though: Many programs seem to open files (e.g. configuration files) speculatively, and if they don't exist, fall back to defaults.

It also requires elevated (i.e. `root`) privileges:

```
sudo opensnoop
```

It's ideal for answering questions like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/355903/is-there-a-way-to-manage-and-sort-lots-of-wireless-networks-on-os-x/355971#355971): Run `opensnoop | grep plist` to monitor all `.plist` configuration file changes, and change some settings in System Preferences to find out where they're stored on disk.

---

You can also inspect the processes in `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app`. Select a process in the list, then *View » Inspect Process » Open Files and Ports*.

---

You can also use [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start), a GUI utility for monitoring file system changes.

[image]

(Thanks [@Chealion](https://superuser.com/users/1339/chealion)!)

Comment: I use the 'Activity Monitor.app' to monitor the total hdd i/o

Comment: The problem is, I dont know the program causing the high i/o

Comment: @user Then use `fs_usage` to see which program name you come across often enough and filter afterwards.

Comment: [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) is a decent GUI to fs_usage.