# Is there a way to manage and sort lots of wireless networks on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, airport, system-preferences

On OS X you can manage your wireless networks; that is drag them to set preferred order, delete ones you don't want any more, etc.

The only problem is that there is a tiny window which only shows ~4 networks at a time.

Is there some way to be able to see more of the networks at once, and perhaps sort by name?

[image]

Comment: If you ever wondered how I know about all those obscure configuration files, [here's an explanation](http://superuser.com/posts/240935/revisions) ;-)

Comment: I actually did wonder about that. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to change the layout of that dialog. As it doesn't support custom sorting and resizing, you can't change that.

---

But the source for this list is accessible from the following file:

`/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`

You can open/read the file in any text editor, Property List Editor/Xcode 4, `PlistBuddy` or `defaults`.

To get the full list of networks:

> `defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences RememberedNetworks | grep SSIDString | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d';' -f1`

To also sort the list of network names case-insensitively:

> `defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences RememberedNetworks | grep SSIDString | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d';' -f1 | sort -f`

To print both the network name and the security type (like in the list), use:

> `defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences RememberedNetworks | grep -E "(SSIDString|SecurityType)" | cut -d= -f2 | sed -e 'N;s/\n/ /' -e 's|;||g'`

Comment: On OS X 10.10 the value is no longer RememberedNetworks but KnownNetworks instead. The same commands work if you substitute in the new value instead.